# Load depending Dlls dynamically from a dll using appdomain - ResolveEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, dll

HI all

I have a dll c#.net project and it refers some other sub dlls. The exe application which uses my main dll is in another folder and it dynamically load the main dll using "Assembly.LoadFile". My problem is since other sub dlls are in the folder of the main dll exists, exe couldn't load the main dll.(because the dependencies of the main dll is not available in the exe path.) but when I copy the sub dlls into exe folder and dynamically load the main dll it works fine. I want to keep all dlls in one folder and dynamically load main dll. How can I resolve this problem? (All are C#/.net2.0 Projects)

Will Appdomain-ResolveEventHandler Delegate help me to solve this?

Thanks
Regards,
Robo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what you need to solve your assembly loading problems.  If you subscribe to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, you will be called when the CLR tries to bind to an assembly and fails.  The event passes you a `ResolveEventArgs` parameter that contain the name of the failed assembly and then you can manually call `Assembly.LoadFrom` with the path of your choice and return that assembly instead.

Comment: Thanks Rick. In my case I don't have any control on Exe application. It can load the my main Dll whatever Its desire way. I need to handle assembly resolve problem into my main dll. Is it doable? (resolve assembly inside dll) Or Do I need to ask the Exe developer to resolve the assemblies?

Comment: @RoboAlex: All problems in computer science can be solved with one more level of indirection.  You need a top-level DLL with no dependencies.  From that hook the event and then load your real main DLL with dependencies.